# How to test the android devices remotely?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to test the android device applications remotely.I mean the devices will be in different regions and the tester will be able to test the application remotely.

Can anyone suggest me great option to do it ?

Comment: Moderators here on SO don't understand the real question and a fake question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use DeviceAnyWhere for the same, it works like rda tool provided by nokia.

Comment: I want the open source tool to perform it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use an emulator. Why do you even need the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ADB option to debug the device remotely (assuming network is available).